using the book .net maui for C# developers trying to get snackbar to work in windows
Getting this error when I try the sample in .net maui for c# developers.

Message=Additional setup is required in the Package.appxmanifest file to enable Snackbar on Windows.

Additonally, UseMauiCommunityToolkit(options => options.SetShouldEnableSnackbarOnWindows(true); must be called to enable Snackbar on Windows. See the Platform Specific Initialization section of the Snackbar documentaion for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/alerts/snackbar
I went to the website and made the changes as below from https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/alerts/snackbar
Here's the code from mauiProgram.cs
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder().UseMauiCommunityToolkit(options => options.SetShouldEnableSnackbarOnWindows(true));
    builder
      .UseMauiApp<App>()
      .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
      .UseMauiCommunityToolkitMarkup()
      .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
      {
          fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
          fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
      });

Changes made in the package.appxmanifes files
 xmlns:com="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/com/windows10"
xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"

  IgnorableNamespaces="uap rescap desktop">

The program starts then get the message of unhandled exceptions. I am losted on where to look. tried to find simple samples online. Note toast works on the site.

You missed a step from the docs: “ In Package.appxmanifest, inside of each  tag, add the following extensions:”

Are you running in packaged (windows store) or in standalone mode? The snackbar didn't work in standalone mode at all. There was a fix, but I'm not sure whether it has been released already.

I can reproduce your problem and I fixed it by adding the steps Jason said:

In Package.appxmanifest, inside of each <Application> tag, add the following extensions:


<Extensions>

   <!-- Specify which CLSID to activate when notification is clicked -->
   <desktop:Extension Category="windows.toastNotificationActivation">
       <desktop:ToastNotificationActivation ToastActivatorCLSID="6e919706-2634-4d97-a93c-2213b2acc334" /> 
   </desktop:Extension>

   <!-- Register COM CLSID -->
   <com:Extension Category="windows.comServer">
       <com:ComServer>
           <com:ExeServer Executable="YOUR-PATH-TO-EXECUTABLE" DisplayName="$targetnametoken$" Arguments="----AppNotificationActivated:"> <!-- Example path to executable: CommunityToolkit.Maui.Sample\CommunityToolkit.Maui.Sample.exe -->
               <com:Class Id="6e919706-2634-4d97-a93c-2213b2acc334" />
           </com:ExeServer>
       </com:ComServer>
   </com:Extension>

</Extensions>

And I checked the sample in the github repo. The Executable="YOUR-PATH-TO-EXECUTABLE" for your project should be Executable="Your prject name\Your project name.exe". In my project, it's Executable="MauiAppTest\MauiAppTest.exe" and the snack bar can show correctly.
